# Using coppersmith for bounded solution of a short linear Diophantine problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

I have a $3$-variable linear Diophantine equation

$$ax+by+cz=r$$ where $a,b,c,r\in\mathbb Z$ are known and can be as large in magnitude as needed and I know the equation has a solution $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$ which are bounded in magnitude by $T$ where number of bits in $T$ is order of tens of thousands of bits. We can assume magnitude of $a,b,c,r$ is bound below by $T^c$ where $c\geq4$.

Euclid's algorithm gives some solution but not the needed solution. Barvinok's algorithm has complexity $(\log T)^6$ or so which is very prohibitive. Moreover ILP may not be needed as this is a single equality.

> Is there a way to solve the problem using Coppersmith's algorithm and if so how?

Comment: I'm very confused what the problem here is - you say Euclid gives you "some solution but not the needed solution" - what solution is needed?

Comment: Solution need not be bounded by $T$ for Euclid!! Directly searching for such a solution directly will be prohibitive.